# How to return just the mode using SciPy

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, mode

I am trying to display the mode of a population on a graph, but I am not able to.  I can calculate mode:

```
    stats.mode(rec)
```

which returns:

```
    mode: ModeResult(mode=array([0.784]), count=array([8]))
```

but when I go to graph it with:

```
   plt.text(0.70, 14, r'Mode = {0:.2f}'.format(stats.mode(rec)))
```

I can't display it because SciPy has gien too many variables to display ~just~ the mode

Can I get SciPy to give me just the mode (ie 0.784, in this case), without having to do it manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the return value is a ModeResult object. If you inspect this object with `dir(mode)`, then you can get a list of its attributes. In this case, you want the `mode` attribute, which as you can see is actually an array, so here's my suggestion:

```py
mode = stats.mode(rec).mode[0]
plt.text(0.70, 14, r'Mode = {0:.2f}'.format(mode))
```